# Pandas groupby get max regardless of sign

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['chart.a', 'dim1', -10],
        ['chart.a', 'dim2', 5],
        ['chart.a', 'dim3', 9],
        ['chart.b', 'dimb1', -1],
        ['chart.b', 'dimb2', 2],
    ], columns=['chart', 'dim', 'z']
)
```

I want to do a group by to get the maximum value regardless of sign. So something like this:

```
df.groupby('chart').agg({'z': ['max']})
```

Which returns

```
          z
        max
chart      
chart.a   9
chart.b   2
```

But what i actually want is

```
          z
        max
chart      
chart.a -10
chart.b   2
```

e.g. for `chart.a` the largest abs value is -10 so return that and for `chart.b` it is 2 so return that.

So i want to do the groupby regardless of sign and just in terms of the abs values but keep the sign in the max value i return.

Comment: I'm glad you've possibly found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Comment: got it thanks. accepted a much better solution than my own one in the end :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this script instead of simple agg

```
df.groupby('chart').agg({'z': lambda x: max(x, key=abs)})
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can just create an `abs` version of the `z` column and groupby with the normal `max`. Might be faster than using `lambda`.